# Clearing multiple-selection list box choices when another field changes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, infopath

I have two fields on a form. Category and Sub Category. Category is a drop-down list box and Sub Category is a multiple-selection list box that is filtered by the Category drop-down.

Everything is working (mostly). The problem I'm having is that if I make a Category selection then make a couple of Sub Category choices and then change my mind to a different Category, the previous Sub Category selections are still shown in the list by their lookup IDs.

It's easier to show than explain. 
[image]

I was thinking I could somehow put a rule on the Category field so that it resets or clears the Sub Category field whenever the Category field is changed. I know I can set a field's value but I can't figure out how to clear the Sub Category multiple-selection choices. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add managed  rules on the "Category" field to achieve this.

1.Click category field-> Managed Rules-> New-> Action

[image]

2. Do not change the condition. Add action "Set a field's value"

[image]

3.Set the Sub Category field value. Just leave the value blank.

[image]
[image]